# Converting a Varchar to date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been stuck with an Update query which I am using in a after Insert trigger

The query is as below :

```
UPDATE ARGUS_APP.CMN_REG_REPORTS CARR 
   SET CARR.DATE_SUBMITTED = (
                               SELECT M.ACKNOWLEDGMENTHEADER.MESSAGEDATE MESSAGEDATE 
                                 FROM MESSAGES M 
                                where M.ACKNOWLEDGMENTHEADER.MESSAGESENDERIDENTIFIER='PMDA'
                              )
 WHERE CARR.ESM_REPORT_ID IN (
                               select report_id 
                                 from esm_owner.safetyreport sr,
                                      esm_owner.MESSAGES M 
                                where m.msg_id  = sr.msg_id 
                             );
```

I am trying to update the  column `CARR.DATE_SUBMITTED` with the value of the select statement

```
SELECT M.ACKNOWLEDGMENTHEADER.MESSAGEDATE MESSAGEDATE 
  FROM MESSAGES M 
 where M.ACKNOWLEDGMENTHEADER.MESSAGESENDERIDENTIFIER='PMDA'"
```

The output of the select statement is in the Varchar format like this `20130918224413`
and the resultant column `CARR.DATE_SUBMITTED` is a DATE field like this  `9/18/2013 12:31:00 PM`

Please help me in this

Comment: But how will I use my select statement in the STR_TO_Date syntex  which is like this :STR_TO_DATE(string, format)

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE` is not a valid Oracle function.

Answer (score 1):

DATE columns have no format of their own, they are converted to a human-readable format by tools, or by using specific formats in the to_char function.

To convert a varchar2 to a date you use TO_DATE() with the correct format. In your case, it would probably be:

```
To_Date(M.ACKNOWLEDGMENTHEADER.MESSAGEDATE,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
```

Comment: @ David Aldridge Thanks this one worked for me : Select To_Date(M.ACKNOWLEDGMENTHEADER.MESSAGEDATE,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') MEssagedate from Messages M where M.ACKNOWLEDGMENTHEADER.MESSAGESENDERIDENTIFIER='PMDA'

Comment: If this answered your question, it would be polite to mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert a string literal to a value of `date` datatype you need to use `to_date()` function:

```
to_date(varchar2_col_name, 'yyyymmddhh24miss')
```

Note: Oracle does not store dates in any particular format - you display them in any format you like by using `to_char()` function:

```
to_char(date_column, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss PM')
```

Note: Meridian indicators `PM`, `AM` are interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

As other has already said the TO_DATE function is what you should use. I can also see that you have already fixed your select, but for other people using TO_DATE() its important to understand the format mask, if used incorrectly it can give unwanted to result. Easy misstakes, such as using a 12 hour-clock, mixing up minutes with months etc can be avoided.

I recommend having a sheet available with the allowed mask parameters

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

I know you asked Date but oracle also have a TO_TIMESTAMP function to convert strings to timestamps. The parameters are less

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_timestamp.php

Dates and timestamp are different in that timestamps have fractional seconds and their arithmetic are different. Subtracting/Adding two timestamps will give an intervale while two dates give another date.